# Java generics warnings on java.util.Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a method:

```
public List<Stuff> sortStuff(List<Stuff> toSort) {
    java.util.Collections.sort(toSort);

    return toSort;
}
```

This produces a warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked invocation sort(List<Stuff>) of the generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections.
```

Eclipse says the only way to fix the warning is to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to my `sortStuff` method. That seems like a crummy way to do with something that is built into Java itself.

Is this really my only option here? Why or why not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the actual code that produces the error? Seeing the code for "Stuff" might help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) expects that `T` must implement `Comparable<? super T>`. It seems like `Stuff` does implement `Comparable` but doesn't provide the generic type argument.

Make sure to declare this:

```
public class Stuff implements Comparable<Stuff>
```

Instead of this:

```
public class Stuff implements Comparable
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me.  I was implementing Comparator and changed it to Comparator<ObjectClassName> (for example) to match the parameters of the class's compare function.

Answer (score 6):

Do tou use this:

```
// Bad Code
public class Stuff implements Comparable{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        // TODO
        return ...
    }

}
```

or this?

```
// GoodCode
public class Stuff implements Comparable<Stuff>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Stuff o) {
        // TODO
        return ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the return type of your method

Answer (score 0):

[Sorting Generic Collections](http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=21)

There are two sorting functions defined in this class, shown below:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);

public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c);
```

Neither one of these is exactly easy on the eyes and both include the wildcard (?) operator in their definitions. The first version accepts a List only if T extends Comparable directly or a generic instantiation of Comparable which takes T or a superclass as a generic parameter. The second version takes a List and a Comparator instantiated with T or a supertype.