# Generics and Java warning

Tags: java, generics

I know this topic has been discussed quiet a while for now (e.g, [Java generics warnings on java.util.Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501884/java-generics-warnings-on-java-util-collections), [java generics, unchecked warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009226/java-generics-unchecked-warnings), etc) but I am facing a situation for which I cannot find an explanation.

I have a Predicate class defined as

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean holds(T o) ; 
}
```

Then, I have a utility class (PredicateUtils) to compose predicates. An example method in there is

```
public static <T> Predicate join(final Predicate<T> p1, final Predicate<T> p2) {
    return new Predicate<T>() {

        @Override
        public boolean holds(T o) {
            return (p1.holds(o) && p2.holds(o)) ;
        }
    } ;
}
```

However, when I call a join method, for instance, passing two Predicate instances, I get the following error from the jdk (javac 1.7.0_51) compiler:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        return PredicateUtils.join(p1, p2) 
  required: Predicate<Integer>
  found:    Predicate
```

To simplify the discussion, once can define the method bellow (dummy code) in a given class:

```
public static Predicate<Integer> test() {
    Predicate<Integer> p1 = new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean holds(Integer o) { return true ; }
    };
    Predicate<Integer> p2 = new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean holds(Integer o) { return true ; }
    };
    return join(p1, p2) ;
}
```

and will see that upon the compilation of the associated class, javac issues the same warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice the return type of your `join` method:

```
public static <T> Predicate join(final Predicate<T> p1, final Predicate<T> p2)
```

You're using raw type, and hence that warning. Change it to:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> join(final Predicate<T> p1, final Predicate<T> p2)
```

Comment: Indeed. I missed that :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As the compiler is trying to tell you, your method returns `Predicate`, not `Predicate<T>`.

Don't do that.

If you make a generic class, you should always use it with generic parameters.

Comment: Sure, that was not the intention, but rather a slip up. Thanks.